# Access SD card data from android for work app

Tags: android, profile, android-sdcard, airwatch, android-for-work

My EMM is VMWare Airwatch, and I have successfully setup the android for work environment and installed the work profile on my Nexus 5x device.
But my work apps are not able to access the SD data, or files stored on external storage.

I have tried creating and installing Android for work profile. In the Airwatch console under profiles I have also enabled the 'Sync and Storage' options under the Restrictions section of work profile.

Is this the expected behaviour of work apps. As the primary feature of my application is to access SD card data.
Please help me out, if I am missing something.

Comment: Check these: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html  Also make sure you have permissions added.

Comment: AfW devices must be entirely encrypted, it could be the reason why apps can't access the SD card. It's just a theory though

Comment: Regular apps can access sd card even if the device is encrypted. I think awf considers sdcard as personal data, and hence doesn't allow work apps to access them.

Answer (score 3):

After a long conversation with the Airwatch support team, they have confirmed that the in a Work profile enrolled device, you would not be able to access SD card data from a work application, and it is as per design.