# How to access personal file in SD card in work profile App?

Tags: android, android-multiple-users, android-managed-profile

According to Google's introduction https://developer.android.com/work/managed-profiles.html, personal files in SD cards are not accessible by work profile application. However, we can see all files in DocumentsUI(application provided by system) by click "personality" after sending `Intent(ACTION_GET_CONTENT)`, moreover file name, size and date are shown, which seems that files are readable. But when we use the uri from `onActivityResult` I got `FileNotException (EACCES: permission denied)` if I do reading operation (`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission is already granted). Can we access these personal files from a work profile applications? If yes, how can I read and write them?

Thanks in advance!

Reference question @ [Access SD card data from android for work app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827612/access-sd-card-data-from-android-for-work-app), is the answer true?

Comment: Did you check this link: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: Yes, I did. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

With more test, I'm able to access some video/audio/picture files from DocumentsUI(by system). But for more files provided by 3rd-party application(such as file explorer), failure still exist. I suppose that the result depends on file providers. If content uri returned with read permission granted, application in work profile is able to read.